# How do I load my UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` that is being populated by `UIImage` according to which button was tapped to segue into the `UICollectionView`. Regardless of which button is tapped, the `UICollectionView` is being populated via a Parse.com query.

When I put the code for the query inside the button's code, the query completes, but the `UICollectionView` is blank. For some reason, the code in the button has virtually no effect on the `UICollectionView`. How can I get my images to appear?

Another note: When I tap the button the first time, the query completes, but the images do not appear. But when I tap "Back" and tape the button a second time, the images all appear.

**Query code:**

```
var images = [UIImage]()
var parseObjects = [PFFile]()
var imageNames = [String]()
var imageExpansions = [String]()

class selectExpansionViewController: UIViewController {

@IBAction func xy1Button(sender: AnyObject) {
}

@IBAction func xy2Button(sender: AnyObject) {

    var downloadCards = PFQuery(className: "Cards")
    //downloadCards.whereKey("Expansion", equalTo:"XY2")
    downloadCards.limit = 200
    downloadCards.orderByAscending("Number")
    downloadCards.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {

        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) cards.")
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
                    parseObjects.append(object["Image"] as! PFFile)
                    imageNames.append(object["Number"] as! String)
                    imageExpansions.append(object["Expansion"] as! String)
                }
            }
        } else {
            println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
        }
    }

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("jumpToCollectionView", sender: self)

}
```

`UICollectionView` code:

```
class CollectionCollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return parseObjects.count

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell: CardsCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CardsCollectionViewCell
    parseObjects[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{

        (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)

            cell.cardsImg.image = image

        }   

    }
    cell.cardLabel.text = imageNames[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

}

May be helpful:
When I put the code for the query into `viewDidLoad` on the view with all of the buttons, I can tap on a button and the `UICollectionView` DOES work. The only problem is that I am unable to filter out images that I don't want unless I click the button. And I run into the same problem: all code inside the button has no effect on the `UICollectionView`.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I needed to put my query code inside UICollectionView's viewDidLoad method. Also needed to create variable that each button can change to determine which images were queried.